# Constructor not defined: [PbxmlGroupConnection].<Constructor>(DataSource.ConnectionParams)

Tags: apex, constructor

```
global class PbxmlGroupProvider extends DataSource.Provider {

    override global List<DataSource.AuthenticationCapability> getAuthenticationCapabilities() {
        List<DataSource.AuthenticationCapability> capabilities = new List<DataSource.AuthenticationCapability>();
        capabilities.add(DataSource.AuthenticationCapability.ANONYMOUS);
        capabilities.add(DataSource.AuthenticationCapability.BASIC);
        return capabilities;
    }

    override global List<DataSource.Capability> getCapabilities() {
        List<DataSource.Capability> capabilities = new List<DataSource.Capability>();

        capabilities.add(DataSource.Capability.ROW_QUERY);
        capabilities.add(DataSource.Capability.SEARCH);
        return capabilities;
    }

    override global DataSource.Connection getConnection(DataSource.ConnectionParams connectionParams) {
        return new PbxmlGroupConnection(connectionParams);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message explains that the class `PbxmlGroupConnection` does **not** have this constructor:

```
global PbxmlGroupConnection {

    global PbxmlGroupConnection(DataSource.ConnectionParams connectionParams) {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

but you are trying to call that constructor here:

```
        return new PbxmlGroupConnection(connectionParams);
```

So either change the calling code to use or change that class to fix this.